# Find a discontinuous linear transformation from the set of bounded real sequences to the reals

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, continuity, linear-transformations

I am looking for a linear transformation T: B(N,R) -> R, with R the real numbers and B(N,R) the set of all bounded real sequences (with the sup norm), that is discontinuous. I first thought that the transformation could be adding up all the values, and then I could find a sequence of sequences with |(x_n)| -> 0 but ||T(x_n)|| /infinity is constant. But unfortunately this doesn’t work because for non-zero constant sequences for example, they would be mapped to „infinity“ which is not an element of the real numbers… Could you please help me?

Comment: You cannot find an explicit example of such discontinuous linear form : it requires the axiom of choice.